# Success callback in $http promise isn't happening

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing an angular app that consumes a RESTful API. I'm handling the authentication of the user this way:

```
// in services.js

app.factory('authService', ['$http', '$q', 'localStorageService', 
  function ($http, $q, localStorageService) {

    var login = function (loginData) {

      var data = "grant_type=something&username=" + loginData.userName + "&password=" + loginData.password;
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $http.post(serviceBase + 'token', data).
        success(function (response) {
          localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token });
          localStorageService.set('personaData', { username: response.username });

          deferred.resolve(response);
        }).
        error(function(err, status) {
          deferred.reject(err);
        });

      return deferred.promise;

    };
```

And the controller

```
// controller.js

app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'authService',
  function ($scope, $state, authService) {
    $scope.loginData = {
      userName: '',
      password: ''
    };

    $scope.alert = {type: '',msg: ''};

    $scope.login = function () {
      authService.login($scope.loginData).
        then(function (response) {
          $state.go('index'); // when the service verify that the auth data is correct, the controller redirects to the principal state 
        }, function (err) {
          $scope.alert = {
            type: 'danger',
            msg: 'non'
          };
        });
    };
  }
]);
```

The problem is when the user sends the correct auth info (meaning username and password), the service does not go through the `.success` callback when the response is 200 OK. And yes, this behaviour is only expected when the response isn't 200 OK.

The exact response of the resource is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 851
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 11 Mar 2015 16:20:12 GMT

{"access_token":"...","token_type":"...","expires_in":"...","username":"...","role":"...","display_name":"..."}
```

What's happening here? How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: If you aren't getting success, are you at least getting error?

Comment: @KevinB yes, when the auth data is wrong, the response is a 400 Bad Request, and the service behaves as expected.

Comment: Right, but when it is correct, and you aren't getting success, are you at least getting error?

Comment: What status code does angular report in that case? I know you've already looked at the network tab, i want to see what angular sees. It's possible that all this time you've been getting CORS errors and just haven't seen them, and assumed that the "error" you were getting on bad credentials were due to the bad credentials and not CORS.

Comment: @KevinB I've already checked CORS, isn't that. For the bad auth info, angular reports the exact status code. For the right auth info, angular doesn't report anything.

Comment: Does angular properly report 400 on wrong credentials?

Comment: @KevinB yes, but doesn't report anything on correct credentials

Comment: You may be running into a forgotten promise issue if an exception is occurring in your localStorageService calls.

Comment: Seems like the only thing left to check would be that the json being returned is valid.

Comment: @KevinB the resource response is in the question. I think is valid json.

Comment: I mean, i'm sure in the actual response the values aren't all "...", so i couldn't be sure, :)

Comment: @KevinB oh sorry, here's the full json http://pastebin.com/VFiPg4s9

Comment: Yup, looks good. Try digging more into the `error` and `status` arguments being passed to that `.error` callback. Compare between a bad creds request and a good creds request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a new promise, you can just return the promise from the $http call - I think an exception is occurring in your call to localStorageService but it's getting lost and your promise is never resolved. You can change your authService to the following and hopefully you'll see the error in localStorageService:

```
app.factory('authService', ['$http', '$q', 'localStorageService', 
  function ($http, $q, localStorageService) {

  var login = function (loginData) {

    var data = "grant_type=something&username=" + loginData.userName + "&password=" + loginData.password;

    return $http.post(serviceBase + 'token', data).
      success(function (response) {
        localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token });
        localStorageService.set('personaData', { username: response.username });

        return response;
    });
  };
```